# Is it fine to call this synchronized method from a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

Simply put, I'm wondering if this changes the behavior. I'm assuming yes, because calling someMethod() will lock the entire object, instead of just the list object? But I'm still new to this synchronization stuff, so I'd like some more educated feedback.

The before:

```
public void run() {
    int i = 0;

    while (!end) {
        synchronized (list) {
            while (list.size() == i) {
                try {
                    list.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The After:

```
public void run() {
    int i = 0;

    while (!end) {
        synchronized (list) {
            while (list.size() == i) {
                someMethod();
            }
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void someMethod() {
    try {
        list.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - the new code has got different semantics, as `someMethod()` is indeed synchronized on the instance it is being invoked on (and as such, that synchronization is entirely unrelated to the one on `list`). However, the call to `someMethod()` will take place while the monitor on `list` is being held, so a call to `run()` is "equally thread safe" with respect to `list`.

On the other hand, you have now introduced the possibility for multiple threads to call `someMethod()` directly at the same time. You have also introduced a (probably unnecessary) potential for deadlock with other threads due to the extra synchronization on the object itself. I would recommend this instead:

```
public void someMethod() {
    synchronized (list) {
        try {
            list.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This method is now safe both for individual use and for being called through `run()` - note that it is safe to synchronize on an object that you have already synchronized on; the thread won't block itself.

Answer (score 2):

With `syncronized` you don't really 'lock' an object. You will just make sure that access from everyone who is **synchronizing** on that specific object is 'regulated' with a lock.

A synchronized method is synchronizing on `this`.

That means, if you enter a `syncronized` block on some object `list` you can call a `syncronized` method without a problem at first

---

Some things to be thought about:

This code doesn't produce a deadlock:

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {
        someMethod();
    }
}

public synchronized void someMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

because you already have the "lock" on `this`, but this:

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized (list) {
        someMethod();
    }
}

public synchronized void someMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

may produce a deadlock with some other thread! You'll have to be really careful if you enter a `synchronized` section within another `synchronized` section